# Google App - where it stores user tokens?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

I'm looking for a pattern of a server Application on Google Cloud.

Let's say I want to create google birthday app.
The users need to install the App from marketplace and grant access to their contact lists via Oauth. The app will have associated Service Account.

App code will run every day 8am connect to service account using service owners keys, then in loop check if user has new contact with birthdays and create a new auto text message to specific number.

What I'm trying to figure out, is how to obtain access tokens or refresh tokens of users who installed the app at once on a future schedule? Is this doable?

Comment: It's not secure. I don't recommend to store user tokens.